# Resetting Swift App After 10 Minutes

Tags: ios, swift, time, appdelegate

I'm making a tip calculator application using Swift. My goal is to reset my application after 10 minutes (in other words set all of my labels to $0.00 and set the defaults back in `NSUserDefaults`).

I put these 3 functions in my ViewController.swift file:

```
func compareTimes(opens: NSDate?, closes: NSDate?) {
    if(opens!.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate-closes!.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate>600) {
        reset()
    }
}
func openApp() {
    openingTime = NSDate()
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    closingTime = defaults.objectForKey(closeKey) as! NSDate?
    if (closingTime != nil) {
        compareTimes(openingTime, closes: closingTime)
    }
}

func closeApp() {
    closingTime = NSDate()
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(closingTime, forKey: closeKey)
}
```

In my AppDelegate I call two of these methods:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    ViewController().closeApp()
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    ViewController().openApp()
}
```

**Note that when the app is closed the time is recorded and when the app is opened the time is also recorded.  These times are compared and if 10 minutes passes `reset()` is called.**

My problem is when `reset()` is called all of my variables that represent UILabels and UITextFields become nil and I get an error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

**Here is my `reset()` method for reference:**

```
func reset() {
    billField.text=""
    tipLabel.text = "+ "+formatter.stringFromNumber(0)!
    totalLabel.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(0)
    total2.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(0)
    total3.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(0)
    total4.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(0)

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject("15", forKey: key1)
    defaults.setObject("18", forKey: key2)
    defaults.setObject("20", forKey: key3)
    defaults.synchronize()
    percentages.append(0.1)
    percentages.append(0.1)
    percentages.append(0.1)
    percentButton.setTitle("15%", forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
    percentButton.setTitle("18%", forSegmentAtIndex: 1)
    percentButton.setTitle("20%", forSegmentAtIndex: 2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that when you say `ViewController().closeApp()` you are allocating a new instance of `ViewController` and calling the `closeApp` function on that instance.  Since you aren't instantiating that instance from your storyboard, none of the outlets are attached and you get a nil reference exception.

You need to invoke the methods on the existing ViewController instance. You can use something like this:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    if let viewController = application.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? ViewController {
        viewController.closeApp()
    }
}


func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    if let viewController = application.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? ViewController {
        viewController.closeApp()
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you instantiate the instance from the storyboard then?  I tried your suggestion, but now it's not calling the closeApp() and openApp() methods at all.

Comment: That still won't help you - you need the instance that is onscreen.  If my code isn't running then it probably means that the conditional downcast is failing and so the current view controller isn't a ViewController.  Set a breakpoint and see what is happening. Or, since you are saving all of your values in NSUserDefaults, simply move the code from the view controller to the app delegate methods and then reload from defaults in `viewWillAppear`